# Spring boot AOP ignores JAX-RS resources registered using @Named

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, aop, named

Working on a simple web application where Spring boot 2.x handles wiring between different components and JAX-RS/Jersey handles REST calls.

A simple configuration like the one below is used for intercepting REST calls.

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class MyAspectConfig {

    @After("execution(public * *..*Resource.*(..))")
    public void afterExec(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("====================== " + joinPoint);
    }
}
```

We have noticed that if JAX-RS resource classes annotated with @Named then the advice above doesn't get invoked. However replacing @Named with @Component fixes the issue.

Is this a known issue/limitation? Aren't @Named and @Component interchangeable?

Comment: This also reported to Spring Boot team 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13571